# What does "pif sur la figure" mean?

Tags: expressions, argot

What is the meaning of these sentences?

> J'ai failli venir de Bretagne pour venir lui mettre un pif sur la figure!
>
> Ça se voit comme un gros pif sur la figure.

Comment: For the second sentence you've already got the answer. The first *pif* is an onomatopoeic interjection meant to express the sound of a blow, not normally  used as a noun as it is here, but the figure of speech is easily understandable to a French native in the [context it was said](http://www.huffingtonpost.fr/jacques-tarnero/alain-finkielkraut-elu-academie_b_5130595.html). As an interjection *pif* is normally repeated twice "*pif ! pif !*"  or followed by *paf*: "pif !paf !" (one for each cheek?). The use of *pif* to express a blow is older than its use for a (usually big) nose.

Answer (score 7):

*Pif* is a familiar / slang term for *nez* (nose) [<sup>wiktionary</sup>](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pif).

> Ça se voit comme un gros pif sur la figure.

→ it is obvious
 (literally: it is visible/outstanding as a fat/big nose on the face.)

The first sentence is unclear for me. Either the person has a very small (or ugly) nose the speaker might want to replace (albeit very weird, 
almost nonsense), or more probably *pif* is used their in the meaning of "a punch". It might be a contraction of the word *bourre-pif* old fashioned slang for a punch in the face[<sup>wiktionnaire</sup>](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bourre-pif).

Comment: A noter que l'expression "comme le nez au milieu de la figure" existe
et d'après mon expérience est plus répandue.

Answer (score 4):

*Pif* is slang for *nez*.

“*Ça se voit comme le nez au milieu de la figure*” is an expression which means “it's obvious”.

Answer (score 3):

Pif est bien l'argot (slang) pour nez. Mais c'est aussi une onomatopée qui sonne comme un coup de poing.

Donc :

- ça se voit comme le pif (nez) au milieu de la figure
- j'irai en Bretagne lui mettre un (coup sur le) pif sur la figure.

Answer (score 3):

Hi i'm French and i can translate for you to understand but my english is not perfect

> Ça se voit comme un gros pif sur la figure.

"It is obvious"

For the first sentence like Stéphane said, Pif is slang for nez(nose).

> J'ai failli venir de Bretagne pour venir lui mettre un pif sur la figure

"I'm almost came from Bretagne for punching him in the face"

The second one is an expression for punch in the face

Answer (score 2):

1) "J'ai failli venir de Bretagne pour venir lui mettre un pif sur la figure!"
On dirait plutôt: "lui mettre un **bourre-pif**" = punch his nose
2) "Ça se voit comme un gros pif sur la figure". dans un registre moins grossier on dirait "Ca se voit comme le nez au milieu de la figure": c'est évident.