# Onomatopée du coup de poing au corps?

Tags: onomatopées

Lorsqu'on imagine un coup de poing assené au visage, une [*onomatopée*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatop%C3%A9e) venant souvent à l'esprit est *pif!* ou *paf!*. Le mot [*pif*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pif) a en plus la vertu d'être associé au nez dans la langue populaire, de manière plus [récente](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/9325/3177). Sur *wikipedia*, les onomatopées associées à un « coup », et dont le sens n'est pas incompatible avec ce dont il est question ici, sont à première vue :

- Klett (coup dans une bagarre) - krrr - [?]
- Paf (coup, gifle)
- Pif (coup, coup léger)
- Plaf (coup)
- Plif (coup très léger)
- Vlam, vlan (claquement de porte, coup asséné)

**Q.** Laquelle de celles-ci, le cas échéant, représente-t-elle le plus fidèlement le coup de poing porté au visage ? Existe-t-il une variante reflétant le coup donné au *corps* (possiblement tributaire du son plus « sourd » que produirait un tel coup) ? Sur quoi s'étayent les réponses à ces questions ?

Comment: Les veilles bandes dessinées et séries télé de Batman utilisaient beaucoup d’onomatopées.

Comment: Générique 1966(tv): _sock!_ - _pow!_ - _zok!_ / _pow!_ - _bif!_ - _bam!_ - _sok!_ - _blap!_ / _whap!_ - _biff!_ - _oooof!_. J'aime bien aussi quand la _Batgirl_ donne des coups de pied, _zap!_ - _zowie!_. Mais que disent Giraud/Jodorowsky, Uderzo/Goscinny, Hergé, Morris et cie?

Comment: toutes ces onomatopées sont anglo-saxonnes …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En partant du fait que les onomatopées suivantes reflètent un coup au visage:

- Paf / Baf
- Pif

Je vous propose simplement de transformer le son pour l'assourdir.
Pour ce faire, partons du [triangle vocalique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_vocalique) qui est une représentation graphique, principalement ordonnée selon la position de la langue, des différentes voyelles.

Utilisons ce triangle comme base pour tenter d'assourdir une sonorité:

- Paf/Baf: [a](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ouverte_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie)

La prononciation du 'a' ici correspond à une voyelle ouverte antérieure non arrondie (coté bas-gauche) du graphique.
Afin d'assourdir la sonorité de cette voyelle il nous faut remonter le graphique vers le haut et la droite pour atteindre les voyelles fermées postérieures non arrondie.

Déplaçons-nous d'abord vers la droite de notre graphique pour transformer notre 'a' en une voyelle ouverte postérieure non arrondi: [ɑ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ouverte_post%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie)
Pâf/bâf (si vous faite la distinction de locution entre "a" et "â")

Transformons encore ce 'â' en une voyelle ouverte postérieure arrondie: [ɒ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ouverte_post%C3%A9rieure_arrondie)
Vous obtenez la sonorité d'un 'a' mélangé à un 'o' comme dans 'hot' en anglais.

A présent que nous avons une voyelle postérieure et arrondie, qui a déjà relativement bien "assourdi" notre sonorité de départ, remontons encore le graphique pour aller vers des voyelles plus fermées:

Voyelle mi-ouverte postérieure arrondie: [ɔ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ouverte_post%C3%A9rieure_arrondie)
Elle sonne comme dans le mot 'sort' ou 'ball' en anglais.

Voyelle mi-fermée postérieure arrondie: [o](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ferm%C3%A9e_post%C3%A9rieure_arrondie)
Elle sonne comme le 'o' de réseau en français.

Enfin, la voyelle fermée postérieure arrondie: [u](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ferm%C3%A9e_post%C3%A9rieure_arrondie)
Qui sonne comme le 'ou' de 'fou'.

Nous avons atteint le coté supérieur-droit du graphique.
Voyons ce que donnent nos onomatopées avec cette sonorité:

- Pouf/Bouf

Tiens, au passage, n'y a t-il pas justement un mot qui correspond à cette sonorité assez sourde qui se produit lorsqu'on s’assoit sur un de ses gros coussins rempli de chiffons ?

- Pif

Afin d'assourdir la sonorité du 'i' de pif, le procédé est le même, mais comme vous vous trouvez déjà du coté supérieur-gauche (voyelle fermée antérieur non arrondie) vous n'avez qu'à vous déplacer vers la droite pour atteindre la voyelle fermée postérieur arrondie)

Les transformations successives donnent:

Voyelle fermée antérieur non arrondie : [i](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ferm%C3%A9e_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie)
Pif, avec un 'i' comme dans "vie"

Voyelle fermée antérieurs arrondie : [y](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ferm%C3%A9e_ant%C3%A9rieure_arrondie)
Son du 'u' comme dans "chute"

Voyelle fermée centrale non arrondie : [ɨ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ferm%C3%A9e_centrale_non_arrondie)
Audible via: [ɨ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ferm%C3%A9e_centrale_non_arrondie)

Voyelle fermées centrale arrondie : [ʉ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ferm%C3%A9e_centrale_arrondie)
Audible via: [ʉ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ferm%C3%A9e_centrale_arrondie)

Voyelle fermée postérieure non arrondie: [ɯ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ferm%C3%A9e_post%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie)
Audible via: [ɯ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ferm%C3%A9e_post%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie)

Et enfin la voyelle fermée postérieur arrondie: [u](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ferm%C3%A9e_post%C3%A9rieure_arrondie)
Pouf !

Pour terminer, je dirais qu'en bande-dessinée il y a également une technique utilisée pour "rallonger" un son ou lui donner plus de force.
Elle peut particulièrement bien s'adapter au bruits des coups ou des chocs :
Vous préfixez votre onomatopée d'un "schh"

Si, "bouf" sonne assez sec, un "schhhbouf" l'est relativement moins.

Et pourquoi pas non plus suffixer ad-libitum notre onomatopée de sa lettre terminale comme pour lui donner un effet d'écho ou une sorte de "résonance"...

Pour conclure, je ne dirais donc qu'une chose :

"Schhhbouffff !"

Comment: Merci, j'ai lu à nouveau; l'utilisation du modèle présenté, le travail sur le son par étape, le rallongement, le suffixe: excellent!

Answer (score 2):

Ils ne sont pas sur votre liste, mais pour le visage il y a aussi « [baffe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baffe) » (‘Formé de l'onomat. baf, exprimant la notion de « gonflé, boursouflé », d'où la notion de « coup »’) et surtout « [claque](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/claque) » (‘de l'onomatopée klakk- exprimant un bruit sec’).

Vu qu’il y a déjà l’expression « Tête à claque » qui concerne claquant la tête/le visage je vote « claque » pour le visage.

Pour le corps, il y a « [tape](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/taper) » (‘Dér. du rad. onomat. tapp- qui évoque un bruit bref et sourd’) et « [frappe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/frapper) » (‘De l'onomatopée frap- « qui marque un choc violent et rapide »’).

Je trouve que ces deux-là reflétent très bien un son « plus sourd », mais vu qu'étymologie de "taper" parle carrément d'« un bruit bref et sourd », je vote pour « tape ».

Comment: Voyons...Pourquoi plus sourds que d'autres? ... Car ils se terminent en "P" qui me semble plus sourde (au moins moins sonores) comme consonne que les autres. Et puis pour distinguer phonétique de onomatopées...bonne question...mais c'est ce que les onomatopées sont, n'est-ce pas, les mots dont les phonétiques resemblent les sons qui représentent les mot, comme tape et frappe? @Amphiteóth

Comment: Merci pour les précisions! Mais à mon avis dans "tape" par exemple, c'est plus le A que le P qui fait la différence non?... si tu compares disons tip/tap/top... c'est le P en finale mais sommes toutes bien différent comme impact. Mais l'onomatopée simule un bruit et ne constitue pas la prononciation d'un mot associé au bruit en soi il me semble? C'est un sujet intéressant; je crois par exemple qu'entre l'anglais et le français il y a une nuance pour le bruit qu'un serpent fait "isss" vs. "ssss"?